# "Hatching" or "hatch" to designate "a pattern of fine lines, used for shading"

Tags: word-choice

I am currently taking a look at some presentations my company made on several features of our software, and I came across several sentences saying that "the software shows a red/blue/whatever color **hatch** to indicate something", meaning that the software shows a pattern of fine lines.

Simply judging by intuition, this sounded not quite right for me; my impression was that:

- the word "hatching" was the most common noun to describe such a pattern;
- "hatch" on the other side could be used as an adjective ("hatch pattern"), but was generally not common as a noun that designates such a pattern.

A quick research on merriam-webster shows that "hatching" indeed means "the engraving or drawing of fine lines in close proximity especially to give an effect of shading; also : the pattern so made". But the entry for "hatch" shows, among other definitions, the meaning of "an instance of hatching" or "line; especially : one used to give the effect of shading".

So my question is: is either "hatching" or "hatch" preferable as a designation for "a pattern of fine lines used for shading", or are they completely interchangeable? Is it common to speak of "a hatch" when meaning such a pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search will answer your question

> [What Is Hatching?](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-hatching-1123056)

Your word

> **Hatch**

is not used in this way to describe a pattern, however

> **Hatch Pattern**

is.